# How to handle failover load balancer failure in Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can I catch the *final* exception that caused the Camel failover load balancer to fail (e.g. to prepare a nice (HTTP) response instead of plain stack trace)?

I have something like this:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8081/context")
  .process(frontendProcessor)
  .loadBalance()
    .failover(1,
              false,
              true,
              true,
              MyFancyException.class)
    .to("direct:foo", "direct:bar")
    .end()
  .process(responseProcessor)
  .stop();
```

with:

```
from("direct:foo")
  .process(potentiallyThrowingMyFancyException);
```

(and exactly the same for "direct:bar)

Without the load balancing I'd go ahead and use `onException` but I can't seem to get my head around how this works nicely with the load balancer and its *internal* exception handling. On the one hand, I would like to log the stack trace **DURING** load balancing and on the other hand I want to use `onException` to create a nice error response - and ideally both within the same component/implementation.

So I tried this:

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .process(myErrorProcessor)
  .handled(true)
  .stop();

from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8081/context")
  .process(frontendProcessor)
  .loadBalance()
    .failover(1,
              false,
              true,
              true,
              MyFancyException.class)
    .to("direct:foo", "direct:bar")
    .end()
  .process(responseProcessor)
  .stop();
```

But `handled(true)` seems to break the failover while on the other hand, I assume it's necessary when I use `onException` for rendering the final HTTP error response.

How can I distinguish in an `onException` error processor between:

1. an exception occured which triggers the failover, and
2. the failover load balancer failed entirely and you might want to create a nice *final* error response for the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm more of a [doTry...doCatch](http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html) guy myself :-)

You can enclose your loadBalance EIP inside a doTry...doCatch and treat the final exception in there as you see fit.
Same for the intermediate exceptions: use doTry...doCatch inside your *from("direct:foo")* and *from("direct:bar")* routes and operate on the caught exceptions as you like. Of course, don't forget to rethrow them afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the same approach as Laurent mentioned in his answer. I'll post the solution to have a complete example but accept his answer.

Please note the single but in my case significant addition to his answer, which is disabling the default error handler.

I had to do the following to achieve what I wanted:

1. Leave main route with load balancer as is
2. Deactivate default error handler in the *sub* routes
3. Use `doTry`+`doCatch` with rethrow for debug logging

The routes then look like this.

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .process(myErrorProcessor)
  .handled(true)
  .stop();

from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8081/context")
  .process(frontendProcessor)
  .loadBalance()
  .failover(1,
            false,
            true,
            true,
            MyFancyException.class)
  .to("direct:foo", "direct:bar")
.end()
.process(responseProcessor)
.stop();
```

And this:

```
errorHandler(noErrorHandler());

from("direct:foo")
  .doTry()
  .process(potentiallyThrowingMyFancyException)
  .doCatch(Exception.class)
  .process(logAndRethrowProcessor)
  .end();
```

(same for "direct:bar")